# Combining INSERT INTO & SELECT with a function

Tags: sql

I need to reverse the values in a column and add six trailing zeros. I have been using variations of the following, trying to export into another table, then pull back in etc but I am failing.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (accountnbr2)
     SELECT Accountnbr, REVERSE(AccountNbr)+'000000' AS Backwards
FROM WhateverID
```

I'm halfway there, I just can't get the output of the SELECT statement back into the AccountNbr field. What is the best method to do this?

Comment: need to specify same number of column in insert as well

Comment: `INSERT INTO #TempTable (accountnbr, accountnbr2)`

Comment: You are selecting 2 fields, your insert only has one...

Comment: I think he should be using `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`, since his statement seems to be making use of the values in `Accountnbr` which already exist.

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the values of the `AccountNbr2` column which *already* exists, then you should be doing an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE #TempTable
SET Accountnbr2 = REVERSE(AccountNbr) + '000000'
```

This assumes that a column called `Accountnbr2` already exists, and you simply want to populate it with the reverse of `Accountnbr` with 6 trailing zeroes appended to it.

Comment: Please mark correct if it solved your problem, thanks.